# What are the various options to enhance data rate of 4G network?

Tags: performance, networking, 4g

i was reading about networks and this question stuck in my mind that is there any various options to enhance data rate of 4G network. If yes,then what are those options?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad but some high level points.

Firstly you need to consider what you mean by the data rate and where any slow points are.

Assuming you mean the end to end data rate, from user to some test server on the internet, then in broad terms you need to consider the radio part of the connection, the core mobile network part and the connection from the edge of the core mobile network through the internet to your test server.

Optimising a radio network is very specialised, involving factors like cell size, neighbouring cells, interference, antenna tilt etc.

Optimising the core network is more straightforward and is usually simply a matter of careful capacity planning.

Both of the above are in the hands of the operator so not much you can do if you are not the operator.

For the internet link, all you can really do is ensure the operator has adequate internet connectivity and your test server does too. You could experiment with different test servers located at different points also.

If you have a particular service which needs good data rate or low latency then you may be able to improve performance in a couple of ways.

For example if you are serving large files like video, using a dedicated Content Delivery Network, CDN, to provide your content may help.

If you simply need a higher date rate than a single 4G connection can provide then there are solutions which allow you combine or bind multiple mobile connections together - e.g. https://www.mushroomnetworks.com/portabella/, https://www.patton.com/products/product_detail.asp?id=476 etc